# NativeScript Telerik UI RC6

Tags: telerik, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

After Angular RC6 upgrade I can't get the application running (builds fine). It seems the culprit is nativescript-telerik-ui library. Throws following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Error calling module function 

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/appname/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular/side-drawer-directives.js', line: 5, column: 12
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/appname/files/app/mainModule.js', line: 10, column: 17
    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266


    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4802)

    ...

Error calling module function
```

The first error is this line:

> var di_1 = require('@angular/core/src/di');

The second one is:

> var angular_1 = require('nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular');

It worked fine with RC5.

nativescript-telerik-ui version 0.3.1

tns version 2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer from the nativescript-telerik-ui team here. The current **1.3.1** version of [nativescript-telerik-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-telerik-ui)/[nativescript-telerik-ui-pro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-telerik-ui-pro) was developed while the **RC4** version of Angular 2 was the latest version, which is why that version of the ui plugin is compatible the RC4 version of Angular 2.

We are actively following the developments of the Angular 2 framework and the **RC6 compatibility** is being developed as we speak. You can follow our [nativescript-ui-samples-angular](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular) sdk repository for future updates on anything Angular 2 related.